# Call function in another lisp file

Tags: emacs, load, lisp, common-lisp

I have to write a game in Lisp. In order to make it clear, I wanted to split the code in different .lisp files.

How can I call a function out of a function in the other file?

E.g. file1.lisp has a function called function1 and file2.lisp has a function called function2.
How can I call function2 out of function1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just so you know, there are a variety of different Lisp systems. I'll post the answer for Common Lisp.

The naive way is to use `(load "filename.lisp")`, but that doesn't really work very well after a while. Therefore...

Common Lisp has a library called "ASDF", which handles packaging and file management.  There's a bit of setup to ASDF.

1. Create directory where ASDF looks for files.
2. Add this information to my Lisp system's init file.

I use this in my `.sbclrc` file (assuming that I created a .asdf file in ~) :

```
(pushnew "~/.asdf/" asdf:*central-registry* :test #'equal)
```

I usually use a previously built ASDF file and then modify it.

Here's a sample ASDF file's contents:

```
(asdf:defsystem #:cl-linq
  :depends-on ( #:alexandria #:anaphora)
  :components ((:file "cl-linq"))
  :name "cl-linq"
  :version "0.1"
  :maintainer "Paul Nathan"
  :author "Paul Nathan"
  :licence "LLGPL"
  :description "CL LINQ style interface with strains of SQL"
  :long-description
  "DSL for managing and querying datasets in a SQL/LINQ style
syntax. cl-linq provides a simple and usable set of primitives to
make data examination straightforward. ")
```

I put this code in a file `cl-linq.asd` next to my source code (`cl-linq.lisp`  from the component `"cl-linq"` in the defsystem) and then symlink the `cl-linq.asd` file to my `~/.asdf/` directory.

Within my cl-linq.lisp file I include this:

```
(defpackage :cl-linq
  (:use
   :common-lisp
   :anaphora)
  (:export
   #:query
   #:cl-linq-select))
(in-package :cl-linq)
```

So for your case, I would have 2 components; each with their own defpackage form, exporting the functions out that the other package needed.

For the examples, I've taken the code from [CL-LINQ](https://github.com/pnathan/cl-linq), a project of mine. You are quite free to use it as a template.

Comment: For very simple systems `(load "filename")` is enough

Comment: Thank you very much for this huge answer! I am not sure where I have to add the `.sbclrc` file. I think that I do not have such a big system. WHere do I have to write exactly ths `(load "filename.lisp")` and how can I call the function of the other file? So How can I do, what I was asking?

Comment: @IsaMunich: LOAD would go in the file you want to bring the other functions in to.   `.sbclrc` goes in your `~` directory on OSX and Linux; it's a bit trickier on Windows (Use Linux if you can :) )

Answer (score 1):

This is for Emacs Lisp (aka elisp)

Create a file at this location:  `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

Create a file at this location:  `~/.emacs.d/file1.el`

Create a file at this location:  `~/.emacs.d/file2.el`

Now, open up `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and write (and then save):

```
(load "~/.emacs.d/file1.el")

(load "~/.emacs.d/file2.el")

(defun run-both-functions ()
  (interactive)
    (switch-to-buffer "*Messages*")
    (first-function)
    (sit-for 2)
    (second-function))
```

Now, open up `~/.emacs.d/file1.el` and write (and then save):

```
(defun first-function ()
    (message "My name is Fred."))
```

Now, open up `~/.emacs.d/file2.el` and write (and then save):

```
(defun second-function ()
    (message "My name is George."))
```

Now, restart Emacs and type:  `M-x run-both-functions RET`

Any functions that you put into any of the three (3) files mentioned above will be accessible to other functions.  You will note that `run-both-functions` includes an `(interactive)` statement, which means that the user can call the function with `M-x` or a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the function [load](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_load.htm#load) it can be useful to not specify the file type.

**Loading files: fasl or source**

Instead of `(load "foo.lisp")` one can call `(load "foo")`. Typically Common Lisp provides the feature of compiling Lisp files to *fasl* (*fast load*) files. Those are usually pre-compiled *byte code* or *native code*. Typically the Common Lisp implementation will load the compiled code if a file exists for it. This saves time (because compiled code usually can be loaded much faster than Lisp source code) and the code usually is faster (because a file compiler has compiled it).

Often one uses a function to load the compiled file if it is newer, or first compile the source file to a new compiled file.

**Loading a file, based on the current file being loaded**

In `(load "foo")` the file `foo` is not a complete filename. For example we don't know the directory where it is loaded from. This depends on things like the value of `*default-pathname-defaults*` or in some implementations on a current directory (typical for Unix systems). It may be useful to load the file based on the file we are currently loading - if loading one file triggers more files to be loaded. For this Common Lisp has the variables `*load-pathname*` and `*load-truename*` (which is the real filename as used with the filesystem).

To load a file *foo* in the same directory as the currently loaded file call:

```
(load (merge-pathnames "foo" *load-pathname*))
```

To load a file *foo* in a subdirectory *bar* of the same directory as the currently loaded file call:

```
(load (merge-pathnames "bar/foo" *load-pathname*))
```

Answer (score 0):

With Common Lisp I done it like this:

In `file1.lisp` I define a function `sayHello` and export that function under the package name `helloLisp`

```
(defpackage :helloLisp
    (:use :common-lisp)
    (:export #:sayHello))

(in-package :helloLisp)

(defun sayHello () (print "Hello!"))
```

In the file `file2.lisp` I `require` this file like that:

```
(require "helloLisp" "./file1.lisp")

(helloLisp:sayHello)
```

*Tested with SBCL 1.4.11*