# How to add Header File in LISP

Tags: header, lisp

The question is how to add a header file (and if it is possible) in LISP.
I want just like in C p.e. to create a `"<\file>.h"` in order to load some piece of code just by calling this header file at the start of every `".lisp"` source code.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by a header file?

Comment: @Sylwester You are right to be confused. I will update my original post!

Answer (score 0):

After all its just as simply as 
`(load "bottleRepresentation.lisp")` command.

Details on eLISP implementation are in the following link: [Call function in another lisp file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731546/call-function-in-another-lisp-file)